# Total ionising dose and single event upsets in orbit

Tags: radiation

I've been trying to find figures for the total ionising dose and potential for single event upsets for spacecraft operations but I've ran into a bit of a brick wall. It seems like there is ample information regarding [manned missions](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/284277main_Radiation_MS.pdf) but very little 'raw' information (the manned mission information details the total dose received by the astronaut who will inevitably be protected by the spacecraft to some degree. Am I missing some source of data on this topic? Can anyone suggest a place to look or a paper to gain access to?

Comment: You mean radiation flux density in LEO? If that, then for an overview see e.g. [Space Radiation Effects On Electronic Components In Low-Earth Orbit](http://www.diyspaceexploration.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/space-radiation-effects-on-electronic-components-in-low-earth-orbit.pdf) (PDF) or [The Radiation Environment in Low-Earth Orbit](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3579710) but there's lots of documents on the topic over at [NTRS](http://ntrs.nasa.gov), say [Differential neutron energy spectra measured on spacecraft low Earth orbit](http://naca.larc.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19950019512),...

Comment: @tidalwave I've managed to pull all the information I needed from one of the PDFS you linked to. I'm happy to mark it as an answer if you make it so; but for other users maybe summarise to 100 - 10,000 rad/year total ionising dose and 10E-5 errors/bit-day for commercial hardware.

Answer (score 4):

You can run your own [CREME96 models](https://creme.isde.vanderbilt.edu/).  As for information, there is a ton of it at that site, or just search on CREME96.